# Cant delete disabled subscription

Tags: azure, subscription, billing, cancellation

I took a course on Azure through PluralSight. After the course I disabled the resources but they still showed active. Several weeks later received an e-mail my invoice. I checked and I had over $300 in subscriptions fees. I tried to delete the subscription, App Service and Azure AD and resource group. The subscription status is disabled, I still see the resource group but I click on link it says that it cannot be found. I removed my credit card information. I just received another invoice for $111. I cant create a support request since the system says that I dont have permission even though I am the administrator.

How can I delete these resources and get help from Microsoft a refund. Can someone from Microsoft call me or contact me and I can provide information on the subscription and copies of the invoices

Comment: This is more a question you should ask on a MS forum directly ?

Comment: It was suggested on the Azure Portal to post questions to the Azure forum on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the issue you are experiencing.  Since you don't have an active support contract, you can contact our support team on Twitter [@AzureSupport](https://twitter.com/AzureSupport).  They can point you in the proper direction.

Comment: Thanks Ken. The folks at @AzureSupport were able to put into contact with an Azure Engineer who is looking into the issue for me.